# Redirect alias TLD to lang param URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I managed to find solution but lost it and none of the others work at this point.

I'm interested in redirecting TLD such as `example.fi`, `example.ru` to domains with language parameter. For example URLs should become like this:
Alias `example.fi` should be redirected to `example.fi/?lang=fi` which is the Finnish language homepage.

I've tried different options but none of them work.

I appreciate anyone who takes time to reply.

Comment: Why do you need to redirect to the URL parameter when this information would seem to already be present in the URL?

Comment: @MrWhite At this point all TLDs such as .fi, .ru etc are pointing to main .com domain. The idea is to redirect customers to page with correct language. So if they type in example.fi, they get redirected to Finnish homepage. The structure is currently set to handle languages via URL parameter. I found this rather complicated and not good idea to move around. That's the reason I'm looking such redirect. Its as complicated as it sounds. :)

Comment: Do you only want to redirect the "homepage" (ie. root URL) as in your example or do you want to redirect any URL-path? Could there be other URL parameters on the initial request? What if a _conflicting_ `lang` parameter is on the request. eg. `example.fi/?lang=de`?

Comment: @MrWhite What I want to achieve is to get TLD like example.fi to redirect correct homepage. Currently, that homepage is located at example.com/?lang=fi, so on the URL with the parameter. I do not plan to change the URL structure itself just if .fi domain for example is advertised, people will arrive to homepage with correct language. Right now they are landing on default .com domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- You want to redirect any URL-path, not just the homepage (ie. root URL). (For homepage only see below<sup>***1**</sup>.)
- No other URL parameters are expected on the initial request.
- If there is a *conflicting* `lang` URL parameter, eg. `example.fi/?lang=de` then the `lang` URL parameter is replaced. eg. a redirect to `example.fi/?lang=fi` occurs.
- All domains are of the form `example.<TLD>` (or `www.example.<TLD>`). ie. no domains with a second level TLD like `example.co.uk`.

Try the following near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}@@%1 !^lang=([^.]+)@@\1$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?lang=%1 [R=302,L]
```

The above redirects the following:

- `example.fi/` to `example.fi/?lang=fi`
- `example.fi/foo` to `example.fi/foo?lang=fi`
- `example.fi/foo?lang=de` to `example.fi/foo?lang=fi`
- `example.fi/foo?lang=fi&bar=1` to `example.fi/foo?lang=fi`

The `%1` backreference contains the TLD from the requested *hostname*. This is used by the second condition to check that the appropriate `?lang=<TLD>` query string is not already present in the query string. (This is achieved using an internal backreference `\1` in the *CondPattern*.)  If not then a redirect occurs to the same URL-path, but with the `?lang=<TLD>` query string, overwriting any query string that might have previously been on the request.

This is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301 (permanent) redirect only once you have confirmed that it works as intended.

#### <sup>***1**</sup> Homepage Only

If you specifically only want to append the `lang` URL parameter to the "homepage", ie. the root URL then change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
:
RewriteRule ^$ /?lang=%1 [R=302,L]
```